# 3 пары скобок в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В частности, результаты могут быть использованы для решения задач оперативной океанологии (прогноза развития опасных гидродинамических процессов, экстремальных волнения и течения) и предупреждения связанных с ними возможных аварийных ситуаций, для решения экологических задач (регистрация и прогноз распространения аварийных разливов нефтепродуктов), для наблюдения и предупреждения опасной метеорологической обстановки на море (смерчей, грозовой облачности) и многих других задач.

Можно ли оставить столько скобок в тексте? И правильно ли выбран падеж в скобках?

Comment: Это для диссертации?

Comment: Это статья в научном журнале

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты с существенной редактурой не рассматриваю, если они не запрошены и без них можно обойтись.

По тексту.

> Можно ли оставить столько скобок в тексте?

Количество скобок в научном тексте ничем де-юре не ограничено. Смотреть надо только с позиций удобочитаемости. Здесь она, на мой взгляд, не потеряна.

> И правильно ли выбран падеж в скобках?

Вот это вопрос не такой простой, как может показаться. Обычный в таких случаях прием - подача "раскрывающих" названий и терминов в скобках в именительном падеже. Но и падеж согласования по основному слову не исключен, особенно если без такого согласования нельзя точно указать, какое слово вне скобок раскрывается.

Плохо, однако, смотрится предложения, в которых эти два приема используются одновременно. В вашем случае надо или все привести к именительному падежу, или к родительному. Второй вариант предпочтительнее, поскольку, например, в третьем случае мгновенно восстанавливается подчинение: "наблюдение и предупреждение смерчей, грозовой облачности", в то время как у Sibylla не сразу и поймешь о чем речь, что это за "море" такое, которое одновременно еще и "смерчи и облачность".

Так что я за родительный падеж во всех трех парах скобок.

Answer (score 7):

Предложение лучше упростить, например:

В частности, результаты могут быть использованы для решения задач в области **оперативной океанологии,  экологии и метеорологии**: **прогноз** развития опасных гидродинамических процессов (экстремальные волнения и течения), в том числе предупреждение связанных с ними  аварийных ситуаций; **регистрация** и прогноз распространения аварийных разливов нефтепродуктов; **наблюдение** и предупреждение опасной  обстановки на море (смерчи, грозовая облачность), а также  многих других задач.

Ответы Грамоты.ру по теме согласования: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?p=225490

В скобках допускается оба варианта (с согласованием по падежу и без согласования), в научных текстах предпочтительнее И. п.